# How to separate the dates in area chart of google charts

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization

I'm using google charts and in partivular I have an area chart with many monthly data. However, as you can see in the image below, the dates on x-axis are too much close and is not possible to read them. How can i separate the dates in order to show them? Many thanks!

[image]

and this is my code:

```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>;
   <script type='text/javascript'>;
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});;
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);;

   function drawChart2() {;
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([;
        ['Time', 'Retorno'],;

                for ($x = 0; $x <= count($date_array_all)-1; $x++) {
       ['" . $date_array_all[$x] . "', " . $equity_array_all[$x] . "], ;
                }
   ]);;

        var options = {;
        chartArea: {left: 70, right:50, top: 30, bottom: 50},;
        series: {;
         0: { color: '#469DE4' },},;
              legend: 'none',;
        vAxis: {textStyle:{color: '#7F7F7F'}, baselineColor: '#CCCCCC', format: '#%', gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}},; 
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',;
        hAxis: {textStyle:{color: '#7F7F7F'}}};;
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));;
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'#,###%'});;
        formatter.format(data, 1);;

        chart.draw(data, options);;
        };

    </script>;
    <div id='chart_div2' style='height: 450px;'></div>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try increasing the bottom of the chart area...

```
chartArea: {left: 70, right:50, top: 30, bottom: 72}  // <-- increase bottom here
```

with a *discrete* axis (string values on the x-axis), you also have the following options...

> `hAxis.minTextSpacing` - Minimum horizontal spacing, in pixels, allowed between two adjacent text labels.
>
> `hAxis.showTextEvery` - How many horizontal axis labels to show, where 1 means show every label, 2 means show every other label, and so on.

more control is allowed with a continuous axis (actual date objects on the x-axis)
in this case, you could build an array (`hAxis.ticks`) with the exact values

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how can i show few dates? For example one date for each year instead of three? Thanks again

Comment: many many thanks! I have used hAxis.showTextEvery and it works perfectly. Thanks again!!!!!